# Shrink boundaries on UITableView cell label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm populating a UITableView with data from an array. However, when displaying certain portions of the data, I get a lot of cells with the same text, or very similar text. To fix this, I though I would move the title to the right side of the cell, and fill the left side of the cell with the parent title. There's not nearly enough room in the cell for both titles, so I wanted to wrap the text for both the textLabel and the detailTextLabel, hoping that each label would occupy half of the cell. So I did this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = parentItem.title;

[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.title;

[cell.detailTextLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

However, instead of sharing the space in the label, the textLabel (the one on the left) stretches all the way across the cell now, taking up all of the space. The only way the detailTextLabel shows up at all is if the textLabel breaks before a big word, and leaves some space at the end of the line. How can I get my two labels to share space equally?

Comment: You're not adjusting the `frame` of either label to only be half the space. Also, are you using a standard cell type or a custom cell?

Comment: @Stonz2 it's a standard cell--Right Detail style. As far as I can tell, I'm not allowed to change the frames.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're going to have to create your own custom cell, or at least subclass `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @effendo You can change the frame of the built-in components in `layoutSubviews` in your cell subclass. That said, creating them all from scratch might be the way to go if that gives you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the help--got it figured out!